# Microsoft Access - Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've looked around about this error, but everything seems to be related to permissions issues.

I have an Access 2003 database that has the following update query in it.

```
UPDATE dbo_vdvStockStatus 
INNER JOIN [#tblReport] ON dbo_vdvStockStatus.ItemKey = [#tblReport].MatItemKey 
SET [#tblReport].QtyOnHand = [#tblReport].QtyOnHand-dbo_vdvStockStatus.QtyOnHand
WHERE (((dbo_vdvStockStatus.WhseID)="Q"));
```

The dbo_vdvStockStatus is a view from SQLServer, and #tblReport is a local table in the Access db.  Everything works for this.

So I created a copy of the query, and just changed the view to a different view.

```
UPDATE  dbo_vdvInventoryStatus 
INNER JOIN [#tblReport] ON dbo_vdvInventoryStatus.ItemKey =  [#tblReport].MatItemKey 
SET [#tblReport].QtyOnHand = [#tblReport].QtyOnHand-dbo_vdvInventoryStatus.QtyOnHand
WHERE (((dbo_vdvInventoryStatus.WhseBinID) like "*insp*"));
```

This one, however, gives me the infamous error above.  I tried removing the wild card from the parameter, but it still gives me the error.

Since #tblReport is the same table (and database) I successfully update in the first query, why does it fail on the second?

Comment: This page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800(v=sql.90).aspx, shows some restrictions on updating tables through a view.  Maybe one of them applies to the inventory status view.

Comment: In Access, open the `dbo_vdvInventoryStatus` linked "table" in Design View. (You'll get a warning that the object is a linked table so you'll open it in Design View as read-only. That's fine.) Now look for one or more "key" icons to the left of the field names. Do you see any?

Comment: @Gord.  Nope, I think that was my problem, but I will test at a later date.  I got around it by just pulling in just the table that I need the data from (instead of the whole view) and that worked